# Inefficient entity framework queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a following foreach statement:

```
foreach (var articleId in cleanArticlesIds)
{
    var countArt = context.TrackingInformations.Where(x => x.ArticleId == articleId).Count();
    articleDictionary.Add(articleId, countArt);
}
```

Database looks like this

```
TrackingInformation(Id, ArticleId --some stuff
Article(Id, --some stuff
```

what I want to do is to get all the article ids count from TrackingInformations Table.
For example:

```
ArticleId:1 Count:1
ArticleId:2 Count:8
ArticleId:3 Count:5
ArticleId:4 Count:0
```

so I can have a `dictionary<articleId, count>`

Context is the Entity Framework DbContext. The problem is that this solution works very slow (there are > 10k articles in db and they should rapidly grow)

Comment: What do you define as 'slow'? You should group the data by articleID and use those results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TrackingInformation is a navigatable property of Article, then you can do this:

```
var result=context.Article.Select(a=>new {a.id,Count=a.TrackingInformation.Count()});
```

Putting it into a dictionary is simple as well:

```
var result=context.Article
  .Select(a=>new {a.id,Count=a.TrackingInformation.Count()})
  .ToDictionary(a=>a.id,a=>a.Count);
```

If TrackingInforation isn't a navigatable property, then you can do:

```
var result=context.Article.GroupJoin(
          context.TrackingInformation, 
          foo => foo.id,
          bar => bar.id,
          (x,y) => new { id = x.id, Count = y.Count() })
       .ToDictionary(a=>a.id,a=>a.Count);
```

Comment: You won't encounter the Select n+1 problem (only a single database request), and you don't need to account for missing articles this way either.

Comment: Thanks! That the best solution for me. I just needed to add one where close: 

          var result = context.Articles.GroupJoin(
                                context.TrackingInformations,
                                 art => art.Id,
                                 track => track.ArticleId,
                                 (x, y) => new { id = x.Id, Count = y.Count() }).Where( x=> cleanArticlesIds.Contains(x.id)).ToDictionary(a=>a.id, a=>a.Count);

Comment: Yeah, me and ilya were just discussing that down below.

Answer (score 4):

Try next query to gather grouped data and them add missing information. You can try to skip `Select` clause, I don't know if EF can handle `ToDictionary` in good manner.

If you encounter [Select n + 1](http://ayende.com/blog/3732/solving-the-select-n-1-problem) problem (huge amount of database requests), you can add `ToList()` step between `Select` and `ToDictionary`, so that all required information will be brought into memory.

This depends all your mapping configuration, environment, so in order to get good performance, you need to play a little bit with different queries. Main approach is to aggregate as much data as possible at database level with few queries.

```
var articleDictionary = 
    context.TrackingInformations.Where(trackInfo => cleanArticlesIds.Contains(trackInfo.ArticleId))
                                .GroupBy(trackInfo => trackInfo.ArticleId)
                                .Select(grp => new{grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()})
                                .ToDictionary(info => "ArticleId:" + info.Key, 
                                              info => info.Count);

foreach (var missingArticleId in cleanArticlesIds)
{
    if(!articleDictionary.ContainsKey(missingArticleId))
        articleDictionary.add(missingArticleId, 0);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a bad approach, except that you would likely be better off doing a single query to retrieve the tracking information, doing a second LINQ query to retrieve the missing articles via except, unioning them, and finally converting to a dictionary.  This would result in two database calls, and entirely LINQ, but still isn't as efficient as the answer I gave above which has a single database call.

Comment: @RobertMcKee well, in my example I have only 1 database call, adding `missingArticleId` doesn't require any database calls at all.

Comment: I am assuming that cleanArticlesIds is retrieved from the database.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Ask OP, not me. He is already using it in code at first line, if you paid attention. I don't know if he get them from database. Why not from UI? Why not from another service call? I just simply don't know and I want to make as less assumptions, as possible and to focus on a specific task staying as close to the coding style of the author, as possible.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you are going to assume that cleanArticlesIds aren't being retrieved from the database (or may not be), or may not be all the articles, then you should add a where in there to limit the results being pulled from TrackingInformations to just the articleIds in cleanArticleIds as well otherwise you will return articles that aren't in his list.  Which, admittedly I didn't do either, but I was assuming he wanted an entire list of all articles.